# How can I develop with Python libraries in editable mode on databricks?

Tags: python, pip, databricks

On Databricks, it is possible to install Python packages directly from a git repo, or from the dbfs:

```
%pip install git+https://github/myrepo
%pip install /dbfs/my-library-0.0.0-py3-none-any.whl
```

Is there a way to enable a live package development mode, similar to the usage of `pip install -e`, such that the databricks notebook references the library files as is, and it's possible to update the library files on the go?

E.g. something like

```
%pip install /dbfs/my-library/ -e
```

combined with a way to keep my-library up-to-date?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would recommend to adopt the [Databricks Repos](https://docs.databricks.com/repos/index.html) functionality that allows to import Python code into a notebook as a normal package, including the [automatic reload of the code](https://docs.databricks.com/repos/work-with-notebooks-other-files.html#autoreload-for-python-modules) when Python package code changes.

You need to add the following two lines to your notebook that uses the Python package that you're developing:

```
%load_ext autoreload
%autoreload 2
```

Your library is recognized as the Databricks Repos main folders are automatically added to `sys.path`. If your library is in a Repo subfolder, you can add it via:

```
import os, sys
sys.path.append(os.path.abspath('/Workspace/Repos/<username>/path/to/your/library'))
```

This works for the notebook node, however not for worker nodes.

P.S. You can see examples in this [Databricks cookbook](https://docs.databricks.com/_static/notebooks/files-in-repos.html) and in this [repository](https://github.com/alexott/databricks-nutter-repos-demo/blob/master/unit-tests/test_with_arbitrary_files.py#L6).

Comment: There seems to be this shortcoming of this answer:  On the notebook, code changes in the custom library on the Databricks Repo are used as expected dynamically in code execution. However, on workers, e.g. when submitting jobs to workers to use the custom library method like `(sc.parallelize([1,2,3]).map(lambda x: my_custom_library_method(x,1)).collect()` the my_custom_library_method is found, as the workers do not have access to the Databricks Repo. Any thoughts here?

Comment: Hmmm, it should be available on the worker nodes as well. I need to clarify that with developers. What DBR version is used?

Comment: You may need to do import from the inside of your lambda function. Look to the answer from Scott here: https://community.databricks.com/s/question/0D53f00001mUyh2CAC/limitations-with-udfs-wrapping-modules-imported-via-repos-files

Comment: Tried this on DBR 10.4. Do you think 11.2 would solve this ?

Comment: Not sure, needs testing

Comment: @AlexOtt, thanks for the reply, and specially for the repo example. It is extremely useful. How do we behave if [`my_package`](https://github.com/alexott/databricks-nutter-repos-demo/tree/master/my_package) contains dependencies that are not preinstalled?
Normally I'd use a pyproject.toml + setup.cfg / setup.py / requirements.txt.

Comment: You need to install them. With requirements.txt it’s easier - just %pip -U -r requirements.txt at beginning of the notebook

Comment: It kills me that this is the recommended way to develop in DataBricks... but you have my up vote nonetheless.

Comment: You can use IDEs as well. This specific question was about developing in notebooks

Answer (score 1):

You can do %pip install -e in notebook scope. But you will need to do that every time reattach. The code changes does not seem to reload with auto reload since editable mode does not append to syspath; rather a symblink on site-packages.

However editable mode in cluster scope does not seem to work for me

Comment: `%pip install` is always on the notebook level. But have you tried the solution that I posted?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

I did some more test and here are my findings for pip install editable:

(1) If I am currently working on /Workspace/xxx/Repo1, and %pip install -e /Workspace/xxx/Repo2 at Notebook scope, it only get recognized in driver node but not worker nodes when you run RDD. When I did "%pip install -e /Workspace/xxx/Repo2" as notebook scope, the class function in Repo2 I called from Repo1 is fine if such function is used only in driver node. But it failed in worker node as worker node does not append the sys.path with /Workspace/xxx/Repo2. Apparently worker node path is out of sync from driver node after %pip install editable mode.

(2) Manually append sys.path of /Workspace/xxx/Repo2 when working on a notebook at /Workspace/xxx/Repo1: this also works only in driver node but not worker node. To make it work in worker node, you need to append the same sys.path in each worker node job function submission, which is not ideal.

(3) install editable /Workspace/xxx/Repo2 at init-script: this works in both driver node and worker node as this environment path is initialized at cluster init stage. This is the best option in my opinion as it ensure consistency across all notebooks. The only downside is /Workspace is not mounted at cluster init stage so /Workspace is not accessible. I can only make it work for when pip install -e /dbfs/xxx/Repo2

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).